# practical Mosfet circuit Y/N?

Tags: arduino, mosfet

[image: N-ch Mosfet]

Hi
im trying to activate non-logic Mosfet using Arduino
as in img. is that ok or the mosfet will still on?

Comment: How do you plan to turn the MOSFET off again?

Comment: that's what im asking thx

Comment: 1) Messy schematic, not clear what you want to achieve 2) not sure what the 1 kohm resistor is doing in the schematic 3) Use Google to search for images about "Arduino MOSFET circuit" and find plenty of examples how to control a MOSFET from an Arduino.

Comment: I haven't logic-level trans. so this is my only choice beside I want to control this motor with only 1 mosfet.

Comment: But you have a 24V source for the motor so it would be simple enough to use some of that voltage to give the gate of the MOSFET a 10 or 12V input signal. This keeps the ground (0V) common rather than trying to introduce anther -5V source. Also you need to add a diode across the motor or the first time you switch off you can say goodbye to the MOSFET. (see back e.m.f.)

Comment: In your schematic, the motor current must pass through the MOSFET AND R2 to return to the negative terminal of the 24 volt power supply.  R2 will limit the current to no more than 24 mA.

Comment: So is it possible to control motor with only 1 mosfet?if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment here is a simple way of using the 24V supply to switch the MOSFET from the arduino (0 -5V) signal.

[image]

When Q1 (NPN) is turned ON (input 5V to R1) it pulls a small current through R2 and R3. This turns on Q2 (PNP). R4 and R5 divide the 24V (at the collector of Q2) to about 10 to 11V at the gate of the MOSFET turning it fully ON.

When Q1 is turned OFF (input 0V ), Q2 is turned OFF and the voltage at the gate of the MOSFET falls to 0V, turning it off.

D1 shorts out the back emf caused by turning the current through the motor OFF and protects the MOSFET from damage.

Comment: with only 1 mosfet is that possible? thx

Comment: Yes, it a fairly standard interface circuit using common NPN and PNP jelly bean BJTs.